# Is there a place in here for just testing purposes?

Tags: support

Is there a place for just test purposes ? for example i want to post just for testing or for learn something how it works.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [formatting sandbox question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) over on Meta Stack Overflow which you can use for testing the formatting, but I suspect you'll find the existing answers cover most (if not all) of the formatting options available.

What specifically do you want to test?

Comment: I wanted to actualy try post answer but i can't i think it is because of protected question ?

Comment: @Freshblood - which question were you trying to post an answer on and what (if any) error message did you get?

Comment: link that you provide to me for testing formatting sandbox question.

Comment: @Freshblood - Ah. I didn't see that the question was protected. However, you've got 101 reputation on MSO so you should be able to post.

Comment: So at the moment there is no way to testing answer for me :(

Comment: @Freshblood - you could post an answer to this question.

Comment: They changed it so the association bonus doesn't count, so for the purposes of answering a protected question he only has 1 rep on MSO